# How to rewrite URL with country name and all links with / after country name

Tags: javascript, php, url-routing

I want to develop an application in php and javascript where i want to mention name of the city along with the website url i.e. `www.website.com/cityname` and it should open the website `www.website.com`. Also for other pages it should be like `www.website.com/cityname/pagename.php`.

Please provide a solution how to achieve this and how to maintain the web URL `www.website.com/cityname` through out the application life cycle?

I could be able to find the cityname with website url but it doesnt find the page and shows error.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a cookie?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router/)

Answer (score 0):

The city name has to be part of the URL for that.

Look into URL rewrite configurations for the webserver that you use. In Apache HTTPd you can define rewrite rules for example.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ /index.php?city=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The two conditions avoid the actual rule from being applied to existing files or directories. The rule itself captures URLs with only a single path part (no `/`) and redirects them to the `index.php` adding the city as an query string parameter.

Not the PHP script can check for the parameter. You can store it in a cookie or output it in the HTML to access it with JavaScript.

Keeping it in the URL is more difficult. The URL would have to look like `http://example.com/cityname/`. The trailing slash makes the browser recognizes this as a path level so link like `target.php` will be interpreted as `http://example.com/cityname/target.php` - keeping the city name in the URL. But you have to be really careful with relative and absolute links in your HTML output. The rewrite rule will have to be changed for the trailing slash as well.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/ /index.php?city=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: On which file of the wampserver configuration has to be done